# "a valid provisioning file for this executable was not found" in XCode

Tags: iphone, provisioning, xcode3.2

I'm trying to submit my second app to the App Store. I've followed all the instructions to the best of my knowledge, but I keep getting this error when I try to build and run:

"a valid provisioning file for this executable was not found"

I'm letting XCode auto select the profile automatically. The one I'd like to select is greyed out. But the dropdown selection in the Build tab of the Target window says

"profile doesn't match application identifier"

The other thing I don't get about this is that the selection dropdown shows "com.mycompany.myapp" and then "ABCDEDFG.com.mycompany.myapp" (both of those made up) so that I see they don't match. I have the unique identifier profile installed in the Organizer and in plist file.

I'm totally confused. I have followed the instructions in my book a few times and just can't get it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create the Provisioning Profile from your Developer Center and download it to your local machine. From the Xcode menu, open the Organizer, install the downloaded provisioning profile into the Profiles area. Xcode will then link automatically for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I created the provisioning profile for the device during the first app I created. When I started working on the second app and did a dev Build for the device, it worked. I finished the 2nd app, created a new distribution profile for the app and loaded it into XCode, where I can see it the Organizer. Again, under the Code Signing section of the Build tab in Target, the option is grey.

Do I have to redownload the development certificate again since the app was added to it? The only thing I've downloaded and installed since the new app was started and finished, was the new mobileprovion file.

Comment: Make sure when you go to "Get Info" of your target project, under the "Build" tab, the Code Signing value is correct. Under "Any iPhone OS Device", verify if the profile you downloaded is there, otherwise, double check which configuration you are working on, try to change to "All Configurations" and use the same provisioning profile, see if it works.

Comment: Well, one thing I was doing wrong was hitting Build and Run. Apparently, you can't install the Distribution build on your testing device. I didn't know that. I think that is correct. I think I straightened out the app ID issue to. I was able to build and submit to the app store. If I did something wrong, I hope they would let me know during the submission process and not in a few days!

Comment: yeah, I made the same mistake before, you should use the menu to just "Build" the Distribution.